# Mongo Aggregation for inventory stock data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a below schema.

```
{
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    available_in: [{
        variation: {
            type: Number
        },
        variation_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['gm', 'kg', 'ml', 'ltr', 'unit', 'lbs', 'oz', 'pound', 'gallon']
        },
        rate: {
            type: Number
        },
        stock: {
            type: Number
        },
        discount_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['special', 'daily', 'normal', '', ' ']
        },
        discount_percentage: {
            type: Number
        },
        start_date: {
            type: Date
        },
        end_date: {
            type: Date
        },
        discounted_rate: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        is_deleted: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        tax_percentage: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        tax_value: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }],
}
```

I want to fetch out the products which have available_in stock of less than 10 and equals to 0. I tried putting the query in $match , but didnt seem to work.
Like for example :-
i have 5 products and 2 products have one object in available_in array in which the stock is less than 10 or 0, so how to fetch that 2 products through mongo aggregation ?
Any ideas on this .?

Comment: { $match: { "available_in.stock":  {$lt: 10 } } }, did you try this ? could you share a snippet code of what you tried ?

Comment: Thanks but,
As i mentioned , available_in is an array of multiple objects. So i cant use the above code. @Tahero

Comment: try to unwind available_in and then { $match: { "available_in.stock": {$lt: 10 } } }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
db.collection.find({"availabe_in.stock" : {$lt : 10}})
```

or using aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
     $match :{
          "availabe_in.stock" : {$lt : 10}
     }
}])
```

Note : 0 is also less than 10, so you dont need any special `or` query to add `equals to 0` condition

If you want to get only those elements of `available_in` array which match, then you can use below aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind : "$available_in"
},{
    $match : {
        "available_in.stock" : {
            $lt : 10
        }
    }
},{
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        name : {$first : "$name"},
        available_in : {$push : "$available_in"}
    }
}])
```